# replace an array in immutable state by new array -- react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a immutable state in reducer as:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  rates: [], 
  fromDialogOpen: false, 
  mealPlans: [], 
  roomTypes: [], 
  editRateFormOpen: false, 
  rateToEdit: "", 
  selectedDate: moment().toDate(), 
  selectedRoomType: null, 
  selectedMealPlan: null 
});
```

I do an api call that results me either an empty array [] or array of objects

```
[
    0: Object { doubleRackRate: 200, singleRackRate: 120, mealPlan: "AI", … }  
    1: Object { doubleRackRate: 12, singleRackRate: 1200, mealPlan: "AI", … }
    2: Object { doubleRackRate: 12, singleRackRate: 12, mealPlan: "AI", … }
    3: Object { doubleRackRate: 12, singleRackRate: 12, mealPlan: "AI", … }             
    4: Object { doubleRackRate: 12, singleRackRate: 12, mealPlan: "AI", … }   
]
```

sent as action.payload for state update!

As I receive the array from API call I need to update my rates- state to the value I receive - i.e. either an empty array or the array of objects !!

How can I do this?
I tried:

```
return Object.assign( ...state, {rates:action.payload})
```

But this didn't work !!

Comment: Try: return Object.assign({}, state, {
                rates: action.payload || []
            }); . Hope your action.payload is containing the resulted data/array.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea, but your syntax is wrong.

### Option 1

Use Object.assign to change only the rates field.

```
return Object.assign(state, {rates:action.payload})
```

Some may consider this unorthodox, since it changes state directly.

### Option 2

Return a copy of state with only rates changed using spread syntax.

```
return { ...state, rates: action.payload }
```

Further reading: [JS spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

### For immutable.js

```
const { set } = require('immutable')
return set(state, 'rates', action.payload)
```

[Immutable.js documentation explains it in more detail.](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/set)

Comment: This did not work for me !! I could update the array with merge as : `return state .update('rates',rates=>rates.merge(action.payload));` but this is not what I desired.

Comment: ```Object.update``` is not a function. Are you sure ```state``` is an object?

Comment: I infact have state as : `const initialState = fromJS({
  rates:[],
 fromDialogOpen: false,
 mealPlans: [],
 roomTypes:[],
 
 editRateFormOpen:false,
 rateToEdit:"",
  selectedDate:moment().toDate(),
  selectedRoomType:null,
  selectedMealPlan:null
});` and I need to update the `rates:[]` only.

Comment: As I suspected, state is not a vanilla object, but rather an immutable.js immutable object. You had omitted this tidbit in your question. I added a solution for immutable.js users to my answer.

Comment: this worked for me :
`return state .set('rates', action.payload)`
though
`return set(state, 'rates', action.payload)` gave me errors !!
Thank you :)